# Есть ли какие-то стартовые шаблоны кода для проекта, чтобы сразу же начать кодить

Tags: javascript, html, css, scss

В каком-то видео на ютубе увидел, что есть какой-то уже готовая папка начальных кодов (html, css, scss, js и тд) Где можно такую найти?

Comment: Ну со временем у вас тоже может накопиться ряд надежных кусков кода / функций, которые не зависят от конкретной программы, и часто бывают нужны там-сям. Это не что-то особенное.

Comment: Возможно, в том каком-то видео использовался какой-то фреймворк - react, angular, vue и тд. При использовании этих фреймворков вы можете получить начальные файлы :)